# If-else statement and visibility - android

Tags: android, if-statement, visibility

I have five checkboxes in my app along with five progressbars, and have called visibility according to checkboxes to make progressbars visible/gone. so is there any alternative to if-else statements to use in visibility method , cus in that case there are endless possibilities in the five checkboxes so i have to write endless if else statements in order to make the progressbars visible/gone in all the possibilities.

for example- if CheckBox1&checkbox2 are checked, make progressbar2 visible 
             if checkbox1&checkbox3 are checked, make progressbar2 visible

in other words, i want to make Progressbar 1 visible if any One of the checkboxes are checked and progressbar 2 visible if any two are checked and so on..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Progress extends Activity {

    ProgressBar progressBar1;
    ProgressBar progressBar2;

    CheckBox checkBox1;
    CheckBox checkBox2;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences setprefsd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

        setprefsd = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        if (setprefsd.getBoolean("FirstCheckBox", false) == true) {
            checkBox1.setChecked(true);
            updateProgressBars();
        }

        if (setprefsd.getBoolean("SecondCheckBox", false) == true) {
            checkBox2.setChecked(true);
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    }

    public void updateProgressBars() {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many checkboxes and progressbars do you have? You talk about at least 3 but there are only 2 in the code that appears to be the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

You can use the ternary operator to make the visibility change simpler (instead of `if`s).

I guess the approach here would be to count the number of checkboxes, then set the visibilities. You would just have to change your `updateProgressBars()` method like this:

```
public void updateProgressBars() {
    int nbCheckboxes = 0;
    if (checkBox1.isChecked())
        nbCheckboxes++;
    if (checkBox2.isChecked())
        nbCheckboxes++;

    progressBar1.setVisibility(nbCheckboxes >= 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    progressBar2.setVisibility(nbCheckboxes >= 2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

---

### Other remarks

#### IF statement with boolean expressiosn

Your are using constructs such as:

```
if (myBooleanExpression == true)
```

The `== true` is not needed because you're using a boolean expression here. Use instead:

```
if (myBooleanExpression)
```

#### Using arrays for your variables

If you use several numbered variables that have the same kind of purpose, you might want to consider using arrays.

```
public class Progress extends Activity {

    ProgressBar[] progressBars;
    CheckBox[] checkBoxes;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences setprefsd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);

        setprefsd = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        progressBars = new ProgressBar[3]; // 3, or whatever number you have
        progressBars[0] = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); 
        progressBars[1] = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2); 
        progressBars[2] = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

        checkBoxes = new CheckBox[3];  // 3 or whatever number you have
        checkBoxes[0] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBoxes[1] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBoxes[2] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

        checkBoxes[0].setChecked(setprefsd.getBoolean("FirstCheckBox", false));
        checkBoxes[1].setChecked(setprefsd.getBoolean("SecondCheckBox", false));
        checkBoxes[2].setChecked(setprefsd.getBoolean("ThirdCheckBox", false));

        updateProgressBars();
    }

    public void updateProgressBars() {
        int nbCheckBoxes = 0;
        for (CheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
            if (cb.isChecked())
                nbCheckBoxes++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < progressBars.length; i++) {
            progressBars[i].setVisibility(nbCheckboxes > i ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 scenarios to check condition with 9 times.

Like:

```
if (!mCallType.isIncall() && mCallType.isOutcall() && mCallType.isTelecall()) {
  glInCall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  glOutCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  glTeleCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (mCallType.isIncall() && !mCallType.isOutcall() && mCallType.isTelecall()) {
  glOutCall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  glInCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  glTeleCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (mCallType.isIncall() && mCallType.isOutcall() && !mCallType.isTelecall()) {
  glTeleCall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  glOutCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  glInCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
  glOutCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  glInCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  glTeleCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

then don't use ***"IF, ELSE IF"*** condition.

The Best Replacement is ***HashMap***

> ```
> HashMap visiblityManager = new HashMap<>();   // Visibility Manage without if else condition.
> visiblityManager.put(true, View.VISIBLE);
> visiblityManager.put(false, View.GONE);
>
> glInCall.setVisibility((Integer) visiblityManager.get(mCallType.isIncall()));  // This Data comes from API or Database. it is a Boolean data.
> glOutCall.setVisibility((Integer) visiblityManager.get(mCallType.isOutcall())); // This Data comes from API or Database. it is a Boolean data.
> glTeleCall.setVisibility((Integer) visiblityManager.get(mCallType.isTelecall())); // This Data comes from API or Database. it is a Boolean data.
> ```